# JQuery append not working in IE 7

Tags: jquery

Here is my code to insert table rows dynamically. It's not working with ie7. But working with ie8, ie9 ,Chrome, Firefox.

```
for (var lvl=0;lvl<13;lvl++) {
  $("#check-form tbody").append( "<tr />");                 
  for (var fchr=6;fchr<=36;fchr+=3) {
    if (fchr==6)
      $("#check-form tbody").append( "<th scope=\"row\">"+hpa[lvl]+" MB</th>");                 
    $("#check-form tbody").append("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value="+('0'+fchr).slice(-2)+"_"+hpa[lvl]+" id="+('0'+fchr).slice(-2)+"_"+hpa[lvl]+" class=\"chkChart\"></input></td>");
  }
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you please provide more detail of what "not working" means? Also, creating a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net) helps for easier debugging.

Comment: Notice that jquery 2.x does only support IE9+: http://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: Not working in ie 7 means, it's not adding any content to the page.

Comment: I am using jquery 1.10.2 only

Comment: There's no such thing as a `</input>` tag. `<input>` is self-closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine now. Here the code is

```
for(var lvl=0;lvl<13;lvl++)
{
    $("#check-form tbody ").append( "<tr id="+lvl+"/>");                    
    for(var fchr=6;fchr<=36;fchr+=3)
    {
        if(fchr==6)
         $("#check-form tbody #"+lvl).append( "<th>"+hpa[lvl]+" MB</th>");                  
        $("#check-form tbody #"+lvl).append("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value="+('0'+fchr).slice(-2)+"_"+hpa[lvl]+" id="+('0'+fchr).slice(-2)+"_"+hpa[lvl]+" class=\"chkChart\"></input></td>");
    }
}
```

A running Sample for this kind is here http://jsfiddle.net/WHscf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Likely not the cause, but you had a few stray spaces.  Try this first

```
for(var lvl=0;lvl<13;lvl++)
{
    $("#check-form tbody").append("<tr />");                   
    for(var fchr=6;fchr<=36;fchr+=3)
    {
        if(fchr==6)
        $("#check-form tbody").append("<th scope=\"row\">"+hpa[lvl]+" MB</th>");
        $("#check-form tbody").append("<td><input type=\"checkbox\" value="+('0'+fchr).slice(-2)+"_"+hpa[lvl]+" id="+('0'+fchr).slice(-2)+"_"+hpa[lvl]+" class=\"chkChart\"></input></td>");
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to do this (replaced double quotes with single)

```
for(var lvl=0;lvl<13;lvl++)
{
    $('#check-form tbody').append('<tr />');
    for(var fchr=6;fchr<=36;fchr+=3)
    {
        if(fchr==6)
        $('#check-form tbody').append('<th scope="row">' + hpa[lvl]+ ' MB</th>');
        $('#check-form tbody').append('<td><input type="checkbox" value=' + fchr.slice(-2) + '_' + hpa[lvl] + ' id=' + fchr.slice(-2) + '_' + hpa[lvl] + ' class="chkChart"></input></td>');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's solved.

I tried like below.

Check out here at http://jsfiddle.net/WHscf/1/

Comment: Spaces between tokens are almost always irrelevant, I'm not sure why you think that would make a difference.

Comment: @Rajeshkumar Below where?

Comment: @Barmar yeah usually true i just cover all angles just in case.  And glad you got it.  That code is completely different though.

Comment: Coding recommendations that are unrelated to the problem are better off posted as comments, not answers.